# Passing variable back to parent in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am re-writing a tutorial converting the code from Objective-C to swift. The app moves from VC one where there is 3 sliders (Red, Green and Blue) that set the background colour, a label of the colour name and a button that links to the second VC. In the second VC the colour from the first VC is used as the background and the user has a chance to name the colour.

When the user enters the colour name it should return the new colour name to the orginal VC and the label that shows the colour name should show the text entered.

The following is the code that is causing issue:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(nameEntry: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    ViewController().colourLabel.text = nameEntry.text
    nameEntry.resignFirstResponder()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    return true
}
```

The error "**fatal error**: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" is generated. However debugging nameEntry.text has a string in it.

I'm a little stumped. I could try and do a prepare for unwind segue but it is meant to be a tutorial app.

Cheers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ViewController()` actually creates a new instance of your `ViewController`. This is not a reference to the already existing `ViewController`. What you can do is create a weak variable pointing to first ViewController inside the second ViewController and set it at prepareForSegue or when the second View controller is shown.

```
class SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    weak var firstViewController : ViewController?

    // Other code

    func textFieldShouldReturn(nameEntry: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        firstViewController?.colourLabel.text = nameEntry.text
        nameEntry.resignFirstResponder()
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        return true
    }
}
```

Inside First View Controller `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SecondViewController" {

        let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
        secondViewController.firstViewController = self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the view controller returned by ViewController() has not yet loaded its views. You could try checking this in a setter function and storing it for later use once the views have been loaded.

```
class VC : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var colourLabel: UILabel!
    var savedLabelText: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.colourLabel.text = self.savedLabelText
    }

    func setColorLabelText(label: String) {
        if self.isViewLoaded() {
            self.colourLabel.text = label
        }
        else {
            self.savedLabelText = label
        }
    }
}
```